# Convert list of transitions (points in time) to list of states (periods of time)

Tags: sql, self-join

Did something similar long ago, but when I think I'm doing the same thing now, it doesn't work.

A history table is a list of events happening to accounts.  Some of those events are changes in status, in which case a multipurpose Detail column shows the new status.  Sample:

```
... where Event_Type = 'Change_Status';
Acct  Line  Event_Type     Detail
----  ----  -------------  -------
A        1  Change_Status  Created
A        4  Change_Status  Billed
A        7  Change_Status  Paid
A       10  Change_Status  Audited
B        1  Change_Status  Created
B        6  Change_Status  Billed
```

Now it is easy enough to join this to itself and get a table of time **periods** WHERE A.Acct = B.Acct and A.Line < B.Line but two things I'm failing on:

1. I also need to capture the last status, but in that case there is no end (B.*).  I thought a left join would get it (B.Line is null) but it doesn't.
2. Need to eliminate periods that span more than one status, such as A-1 to A-7  Tried both items below, but either one eliminated everything.

   ```
   AND A.LINE = (SELECT Max(Line) FROM Events TEMP  
                 WHERE TEMP.Acct = A.Acct  
                   AND TEMP.Line < B.Line or B.Line is null);    
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Line FROM Events TEMP   
                   WHERE TEMP.Acct = A.Acct  
                     AND TEMP.Line between A.Line and B.Line);
   ```

If any of that is unclear, what I need to create is effectively

```
      Acct  Line     Acct  Line  Status
      ----  ----     ----  ----  -------
from  A        1 To  A        4  Created
from  A        4 To  A        7  Billed
from  A        7 To  A       10  Paid
from  A       10 To              Audited
from  B        1 To  B        6  Created
```

Answer (score 0):

I poked around with this on a postgres 9.1 database (so, ymmv). This is the query i came up with:

```
select
  x.acct, x.line, y.line, x.status
from
  statchanges x
    left join statchanges y on x.acct = y.acct
                           and y.line > x.line
where
  y.line is null or
  (y.line - x.line =
    (select min(y1.line - x1.line)
     from statchanges x1, statchanges y1
     where x1.acct = x.acct
       and x1.line = x.line
       and x1.acct = y1.acct
       and y1.line > x1.line));
```

Important differences: 1- in the join clause, i'm joining on b.line > a.line, rather than a.line < b.line. This appears to be because (on postgres 9.1, at least) `null` is sorted after non-nulls, unless otherwise specified. 2- i'm jumping through some hoops to make sure i get the right `min` in the sub-query: making a very similar join (don't have to do a left join since we don't care about the `null`s), and making sure the `acct` and starting `line` match with the outer query.

I'm not sure if this is completely what you're looking for, but it should hopefully give you some directions to explore.

Comment: I'll have to try it or at least study it.  Math idea didn't occur to me.  I think what I did before (few years back did involve min.  Thanks.

Comment: Still returns nothing at all.

Comment: I should have mentioned SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I fiddled with it some more and with the subquery removed, but most of the end points (y.line is null) are missing!  I am baffled.

Comment: @WGroleau I don't have access to a SQLServer box, but, with your sample data, it returns correct results under postgres. If you run the subquery directly, do you get the expected result? That is, does `select min(y1.line - x1.line) from statchanges x1, statchanges y1 where x1.acct = 'a' and x1.line = 1 and x1.acct=y1.acct and y1.line > x1.line` return '3'?

Comment: Part of the problem is (just dawned on me) that a left join will yield a null on the right only if nothing else is available.  So I must figure out a way to force that.  Maybe a union with max(line).

Comment: @WGroleau Let's try one thing at a time here. Since my query works in a different system, i want to figure out which part of it is behaving differently in your system.

Comment: I certainly appreciate your spending time on this.  Funny that it seemed easy the first time I did it, but that project was canceled and I can't find the pieces.  (Plus it was Jet-SQL so might not help anyway)  Now, one thing at a time .......

Comment: Non-update: Still haven't solved it, but have been given a higher priority assignment.  So, don't know when I'll get back to this.